# Word order in the sentence with the pr.perf

Tags: adverbs, word-order

The sentence:

> It is now a year since we have *last* discussed your future.

Is it common to insert an adjective between the auxilliary and the main verb? I just got used to constructing sentences with the pr.perf in the way `(to have) + (verb)` and nothing between them. Couldn't you clarify?

Comment: *last* is an adverb here. For your example, check [***last***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/last) sense 14 "most recently". I think adverb usage like this is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite ordinary to put an adverb after the tensed auxiliary in a verb construction.

> I have *recently* discovered a new manuscript by Byron.
>   The investigators will soon be able to tell us whether our suspicions are correct.

Note, however, that the perfect is inappropriate where you have it

> It is now a year since we <s>have</s> last discussed your future.

In your sentence *last discussed* locates the discussion in the past, we don't use the present perfect with an exclusively past reference. The perfect might appear in the matrix clause, however, because the preposition *since* designates a timespan which stretches up to the present:

> It has now been a year since we last discussed your future.